# Need Help Speeding Up Package Installations in GitHub Actions

Tags: scratch-org, package-install, continuous-integration, cli, github-actions

Hey Salesforce Community,

We're facing a challenge with our GitHub Actions CI setup, and we could use your insights to make it snappier.

Background:
We recently updated to the latest Salesforce CLI version because of an installation error. But, since the switch, our CI pipeline has slowed down significantly.

The Issues:

- Slow Package Installs: They used to be quick, but now they're taking forever.
- Sluggish Scratch Org Creation: Creating scratch orgs isn't as snappy as it used to be.
- Laggy Test Execution: Running tests inside scratch orgs has become a waiting game.

What We're Looking For:

- Any tips or tricks you've used to speed up operations with the latest Salesforce CLI.
- Have you dealt with similar slowdowns? How did you tackle them?
- Are there ways to identify what's causing these slowdowns?

Our Setup:

- GitHub Actions for CI/CD.
- Running the latest Salesforce CLI.
- Using Salesforce packages for dependencies.

Any help, advice, or shared experiences are much appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.